# Enable button if radio button selected

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I've tried almost all the methods mentioned here and in other websites but still I'm stuck so that's why I'm asking it here.

I've created a form (with out `<form></form>` tags) in this form I'm creating 4 radios buttons using a while loop data is being pulled from a database.

To send data I'm using a JavaScript(Ajax) which is bound to a button click event.

Now I want to keep the submit button disabled until all the filed's are filled the last filed's are the radio buttons I'm tried to use many other ways to do this but nothing happened so any way below is code I'm using.

```
    function checkUrole() {
    var roles = document.getElementById("userRoles"),
        btn = document.getElementById("submit"),
        len = roles.length,
        sel = null;

    for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
        if (roles.checked){
            sel = roles[i].value;
        }
    }
    if (sel === null){
        document.getElementById("msgID").innerHTML = "9";
        btn.disabled = true;
    }else{
        btn.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

And this is my HTML

```
 <label for="userRoles">User Role:</label><br>
        <?php while ($row = $getUserRoleQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <input type="radio" id="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="<?php echo $row["urId"]; ?>" onmousedown="checkUrole()"><?php echo $row["userRole"]; }?>
        <label id="msgID" hidden></label>
        <div id="msg"></div>
```

Basically the HTML will create something like this,

```
<input type="radio" id="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="1" onmousedown="checkUrole()">Admin
<input type="radio" id="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="2" onmousedown="checkUrole()">Manager
<input type="radio" id="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="3" onmousedown="checkUrole()">Team Leader
<input type="radio" id="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="4" onmousedown="checkUrole()">User
```

I don't like write a code like this,

```
if(document.getElementById("userRoles1").checked{
something here;
}else if(document.getElementById("userRoles2").checked{
something here;
}else{
something here;
}
```

above I think makes the program a bit less dynamic 'cos if a new user role is added I've add a new IF to the loop.

So is there any way I solve this and I like to use JavaScript if can.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @zer00ne I solved this problem and below is the finale working code hope this helps any one in the future as well.

My HTML:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../jScripts/userCreatFunctions.js">

<div id="userRoles">
   <input type="radio" name="userRoles" value="1" checked>Admin
   <input type="radio" name="userRoles" value="2">Manager
   <input type="radio" name="userRoles" value="3">Team Leader
   <input type="radio" name="userRoles" value="4">User
</div>
```

My JaveScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*Register the change element to #roles
     || When clicked...*/

    //This code base was originally developed by zer00ne I'm using it under his permission
    //Thanks man.

    var form = document.getElementById('userRoles');

    if (form){
        form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

            /* Determine if the e.target (radio that's clicked)
             || is NOT e.currentTarget (#roles)
             */
            if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

                // Assign variable to e.target
                var target = e.target;

                // Reference the submit button
                var btn = document.querySelector('[name=submit]');

                // Enable submit button
                btn.disabled = false;

                // call rolrDist() passing the target,value
                roleDist(target.value);
            }
        }, false);
    }

    function roleDist(rank) {
        var display = document.getElementById("msg");

        if (rank !== null) {
            display.innerHTML = "All done! You can save";
        } else {
            display.innerHTML = "Please Select User Type";
        }
    }
});
```

Use the `$(document).ready(function () {})` other wise the script get loaded before the DOM which leads to a NULL value making the script none functional.

Comment: Id should be unique.

Comment: Read this on [`required` attribute](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, so here is what I'm guessing:

> - Need to determine the value of a checked radio input
> - Need to enable a submit button that's determined by a checked radio
> - Need to effectively call upon other functions, run additional interactions, etc. depending on what was specifically checked.

**Details are commented in Snippet**

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Reference #roles
var form = document.getElementById('roles');

/* Register the change element to #roles
|| When clicked...
*/
form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

  /* Determine if the e.target (radio that's clicked) 
  || is NOT e.currentTarget (#roles)
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

    // Assign variable to e.target
    var target = e.target;

    // Find the textNode next to target
    var label = target.nextSibling;

    // Reference the #display
    var display = document.getElementById('display');

    // Display the <label>s text and radio value
    display.value = label.textContent + ' - Rank: ' + target.value;

    // Reference the submit button
    var btn = document.querySelector('[type=submit]');

    // Enable submit button
    btn.disabled = false;

    // call rolrDist() passing the target,value
    roleDist(target.value);
  }
}, false);

function roleDist(rank) {

  switch (rank) {
    case '4':
      alert('Rank 4 - Limited Access');
      // Take user to landing page
      break;

    case '3':
    alert('Rank 3 - Basic Access');
    // Take user to dashboard
    break;

    case '2':
      alert('Rank 2 - Advanced Access');
      // Take user to database
      break;

    case '1':
      alert('Rank 1 - Full Access');
      // Take user to admin panel
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
input,
output,
[type=submit] {
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[type=submit] {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<form id='roles'>

  <input type="radio" name="role" value="1">Admin

  <input type="radio" name="role" value="2">Manager

  <input type="radio" name="role" value="3">Team Leader

  <input type="radio" name="role" value="4">User
</form>

<br/>

<label for='display'>Role: </label>
<!-- 
Since #display and submit button are outside of
the <form>, using the form attribute and the
<form>'s #id as the value establishes an 
association between them and <form>
-->
<output id='display' form='roles'></output>

<br/>

<input type='submit' form='roles' disabled>
```

Comment: Your code comes very close well it's does what I want except for the 2 displays I don't want to display anything what I really want to do is make the user select the role so it enables the submit button. Any way I think I can work with this will let you know friend. Thank you.

Comment: No problem Mr. @Jack. Happy coding.

Comment: I used your code altered it to suite my quest more then test it in fiddle it worked then I moved it to my site and bam this error popped up. **index.php:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null** can you tell me what am I doing wrong here.https://jsfiddle.net/71o2nLn1/

Comment: **NVM** my op found my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't need the `id`'s on every input element. You can get an array of the button element by name using `getElementsByName`, here is an example of how you would do "something" based on one of those being checked:

**JS** (Using ES6)

```
const getRadioValue = (name) => {
  const radios = document.getElementsByName(name);
  let val;   
  Object.keys(radios).forEach((obj, i) => {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      val = radios[i].value;
    }
  });
  return val;
} 

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    getRadioValue('userRoles'); // value of checked radio button.
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="form">
  <input type="radio" name="userRoles" value="1">Admin
  <input type="radio" name="userRoles" value="2">Manager
  <input type="radio" name="userRoles" value="3">Team Leader
  <input type="radio" name="userRoles" value="4">User
</div>
```

[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/s5p02eu8/2/)

#### UPDATE - improved

A more efficient method would be using the [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method, this is better because:

> The find method executes the callback function once for each index of the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. If such an element is found, find immediately returns the value of that element.

In other words, it doesn't need to iterate the entire `Array`, once we find what we want it returns.

*Note: Use the below snippets within the `change` event mentioned above to retrieve the checked value.*

**JS** (Using ES6)

```
const getCheckedRadioValue = (name) => {
    const radios = document.getElementsByName(name);
    try {
       // calling .value without a "checked" property will throw an exception.
       return Array.from(radios).find((r, i) => radios[i].checked).value
    } catch(e) { }
} 

getCheckedRadioValue('userRoles');
```

[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mj4ou76p/1/)

**JS** (Without ES6)

```
function getCheckedRadioValue(name) {

  var radios = document.getElementsByName(name);
  var val;

  for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      val = radios[i].value; 
      break;
    }
  }
  return val; // return value of checked radio or undefined if none checked
}

getCheckedRadioValue('userRoles');
```

[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8agsc7fy/1/)

**References**

- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: `Object.keys` works on nodes? I thought keys were the enumerable properties of object literals `var obj = {...}`

Comment: so this can be written under the same function and called as button click mouse down event ?

Comment: `Array.from(radios).forEach(function(obj, idx) {...`

Comment: @Jack yes, you can dynamically pass the name. I will update my code, one moment.

Comment: Thank you will try this and let you know

Comment: @Jack feel free to adjust the JsFiddle, I can happily help you get it working for your specific use case.

Comment: Thank you I managed to get it working using the @zer00ne code.

Answer (score 0):

There is very basic mistake in your markup **you should not use elements with same id's** in

You can use class instead of id (**give class to radioboxes**)

*document.getElementsByClassName("userRoles")*

```
<input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="1" onmousedown="checkUrole()">Admin
```

Rest of your code seems ok

Comment: So getting rid of ID would fix my issue ??

Comment: Yes but you have change your code accordingly like **give class** and use `document.getElementsByClassName("userRoles")` etc.

Comment: You can remove ids, and use `var rads = document.querySelectorAll('[type=radio]');` and you won't have to add extra classes.

Comment: Ah I'me using the same method @zer00ne in my data submission javascript but it looks like this `document.querySelector('input[name="userRoles"]:checked').value`

Comment: querySelectorAll() <==+ **All**